# Background required to understand the mathematical definition of knots and their transformations

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, knot-theory

What are the concepts of math required as a prerequisite to understand Knot Theory?

I'd like to be able to make a humble beginning by being able to mathematically define knots and the non-rigid transformations one can make with knots made of ropes, in real life.

Comment: This is way too vague. The rudiments are pretty intuitive and could be explained in such a way, but then all kinds of things can come into play. What type of understanding do you seek?

Comment: You need to know the concepts of ‘topological embedding’, ‘homotopy’ and ‘isotopy’ at least.

Comment: @quid I think you have made a good point. I'd like to be able to make a humble beginning by being able to mathematically define knots and the non-rigid transformations one can make with knots made of ropes, in real life.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this. I am still not sold on that questions, but let's give it a try. I take back my vote to close.

Comment: Two important concepts are smooth deformations of curves and their invariants...

Comment: A knot is rigorously defined as a topological embedding $ K: \Bbb{S}^{1} \hookrightarrow \Bbb{R}^{3} $. Two knots, $ K_{0} $ and $ K_{1} $,  are said to be **equivalent** iff there exists a continuous map $ I: \Bbb{S}^{1} \times [0,1] \to \Bbb{R}^{3} $ such that (i) $ I(\bullet,x): \Bbb{S}^{1} \to \Bbb{R}^{3} $ is a knot for each $ x \in [0,1] $, (ii) $ I(\bullet,0) = K_{0} $ and (iii) $ I(\bullet,1) = K_{1} $. We call $ I $ an **isotopy**. A **knot invariant** is then a map from the set of knots to some other set such that equivalent knots are mapped to the same object.

Comment: @Pron  I suggest that you tell us your mathematical background.  That might help users give you the specific information you need.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to have an extensive background to understand the fundamental ideas of Knot Theory. I would suggest reading *The Knot Book: An Elementary Introduction to the Mathematical Theory of Knots* by Colin C. Adams. It's an excellent introduction to the subject and it will give you a starting point for further studies.

From the Preface:

> My hope is that this book will excite people about mathematics--that it will motivate them to continue to explore other related areas of mathematics and to proceed to such topics as topology, algebra, differential geometry, and algebraic topology.